# Creating dynamic method names Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

The devise source code shows for the mappings:

```
def self.define_helpers(mapping) #:nodoc:
  mapping = mapping.name

  class_eval <<-METHODS, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
    def authenticate_#{mapping}!(opts={})
      opts[:scope] = :#{mapping}
      warden.authenticate!(opts) if !devise_controller? || opts.delete(:force)
    end

    def #{mapping}_signed_in?
      !!current_#{mapping}
    end

    def current_#{mapping}
      @current_#{mapping} ||= warden.authenticate(scope: :#{mapping})
    end

    def #{mapping}_session
      current_#{mapping} && warden.session(:#{mapping})
    end
  METHODS

  ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
    helper_method "current_#{mapping}", "#{mapping}_signed_in?", "#{mapping}_session"
  end
end
```

Which allows for creation of method `current_user`, `user_signed_in?` and others.

I want to learn how I can create my own dynamic naming for methods like such

When I try to simulate it with this:

```
class Devise
    mapping = "user"
    def self.current_#{mapping}
        puts "hello"
    end
    def self.puts_current
        puts @current_#{user}
    end
end

Devise.current_user
```

I get error: `undefined method 'current_user' for Devise:Class (NoMethodError)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `class_eval` call that Devise is using.  This is what allows them to use string interpolation to create methods on the fly.

Try this:

```
class Devise

  mapping = "user"

  class_eval <<-METHOD
    def self.current_#{mapping}
      puts "hello"
    end
  METHOD

end

Devise.current_user
```

Comment: What does `class_eval` do exactly? And the `METHOD` constant?

Comment: Class eval takes a string input, and evaluates it using the Ruby interpreter, in the context of the class it's in.  So it ends up running `def current_user...`, thereby creating the method.  The `METHOD` is not a constant, that's just a [Ruby heredoc](http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/12/ruby-multiline-strings-here-doc-or.html) which makes it easier to write multi-line strings.  `METHOD` could be `HAPPY`, it wouldn't matter it's not special.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the lines you try to use are in the 'class_eval' block. You may just try

```
class Devise
    mapping = "user"

    class_eval <<-METHODS

    def self.current_#{mapping}
        puts "hello"
    end
    def self.puts_current
        puts @current_#{mapping}
    end

    METHODS
end

Devise.current_user
```

...and this would work. Or read some docs about *class_eval* for understanding.